# using a subdomain as api in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-subdomain

I want to send a request to api as a subdomain like so :

```
https://api.example.com
```

So I have this in server js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const subdomain = require('express-subdomain');

app.use(subdomain('api', require('./_helpers/api')));
```

In the `api.js` inside `_helper` folder I have this:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', fetch);

module.exports = router;

async function fetch(req, res) {
    console.log('fetch api worked');

}
```

But the `console.log('fetch api worked');` never reaches and never execute.

I want to execute the `fetch` function inside `_helper/api.js` . How can I do this?

Comment: You have to do POST request to that endpoint with some client like Postman or programmatically. Then you should return something to the client, or the request will time out.

Comment: the console log should be reached and this is no matter if you return anything or not..

Comment: Did you make the POST request that endpoint?

Comment: of course I did!!!!!

Comment: And what was the response?

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at

Comment: Because the console log not reached ... I get this error

Comment: try the `res.send()`, like @BorisGrigorov says, if it doesn't return and its not hitting the console log then the `req.subdomains` is not being seen so the middleware is not run https://github.com/bmullan91/express-subdomain/blob/master/index.js#L33 its next'ing and you don't have other middleware to fallback on

Comment: and how to fix this?